# ReactiveSwift with MVVM and Action

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

code :

```
init(roomService: RoomService) {
    self.roomService = roomService

    let viewDidLoad = viewModelProperty.signal.skipNil()
    roomAction = Action<(), [Room], NetworkError>(execute: { _ in
        roomService.getRooms()
    })

    roomAction <~ viewDidLoad
    rooms = roomAction.values
    isLoading = roomAction.isExecuting.signal
    networkError = roomAction.errors

}
```

`roomService.getRooms()` returns  `SignalProducer<[Room], NetworkError>`

It is init of my ViewModel but I want to improve my solution and change create CellViewModel inside action. How to do that because I am stuck.

I need something like this: 
`Action<(), [CellViewModel], NetworkError>` where `action.values` will return `Signal<[CellViewModel], NoError>`

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to keep the Action as it is, and then `.map` the action result to `[CellViewModel]` in order to keep the two functions separate and compose-able, e.g.

`rooms = roomAction.values.map(CellViewModel.init)`